# Equivalence of $\operatorname{nullity}= 0$ and injectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am unsure on how to prove one way of the following equivalence:

If we have $T : U \to V$ where $\dim(U)=\dim(V)=n$, then

1. $\operatorname{nullity}(T)=0$
2. $T$ is injective

I know that 1. implies 2. as if $\ker(T)=\{0\}$ and we suppose there exists $T(u_1), T(u_2)$ s.t $T(u_1)=T(u_2)$, then by definition of linear maps we know that $T(u_1 - u_2)=0 \implies u_1 - u_2 \in \ker(T)$ which is equal to $0$, and so $u_1$ must be equal to $u_2$. So $T$ is injective.

I am having difficulty proving the other way though.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have linear $T\colon U\to V$ where $U$, $V$ are vector spaces (of arbitrary, possibly infinite, possibly different dimension), then 
$$ \dim\ker T=0\iff T\text{ is injective}$$

You showed $\implies$. The other direction is even simpler: If $T$ is injective and $Tu=0$, then from $T0=0$ and injectivity $u=0$, so $\ker T=\{0\}$.